# Syntax error : missing '{ ' before '.'

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have an `AVOption` structure:

```
static const AVOption options[] = {  
        COMMON_OPTIONS  // error here
        { NULL }  
    };
```

and `COMMON_OPTIONS` is defined as:

```
#define COMMON_OPTIONS \
{ "interp", "select interpolation mode", OFFSET(interpolation), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT, {.i64=INTERPOLATE_TETRAHEDRAL}, 0, NB_INTERP_MODE-1, FLAGS, "interp_mode" }, \
{NULL}
```

I am getting an error:

```
2>c:\users\awki6\desktop\ffmpeg\libavfilter\vsrc_testsrc.cpp(98): error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before '.'
```

Comment: What does `COMMON_OPTIONS` expand to?

Comment: #define COMMON_OPTIONS \
    { "interp", "select interpolation mode", OFFSET(interpolation), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT, {.i64=INTERPOLATE_TETRAHEDRAL}, 0, NB_INTERP_MODE-1, FLAGS, "interp_mode" }, \ {NULL}

Answer (score 1):

Your `COMMON_OPTIONS` macro has already the `{ NULL }` and does not ends with a `,`, so:

```
static const AVOption options[] = {  
        COMMON_OPTIONS
    };
```

will solve your problem.

**Past answer before the edit:**
Even if we don't know what does `COMMON_OPTIONS` expand to, I guess that you just miss the comma after it:

```
static const AVOption options[] = {  
        COMMON_OPTIONS,
        //            ^
        { NULL }  
    };
```